# @font-face in ie not working

Tags: css, font-face

I am using a font called `samarn` in my website. The font looks good in *Firefox* and *Google Chrome* but in **IE**, it does not show.

My code is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SamarkanNormal';
    src: url('../fonts/samarn.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/samarn.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/samarn.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/samarn.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/samarn.svg#samarn') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

#name { 
    font-family:'SamarkanNormal'; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a copy of this hosted on the web somewhere? The code you posted looks correct from what I can tell.

Comment: Website link is [link](http://achieveee.com/pareekshum) .

Comment: It seems to be working fine on IE9 according to Adobe's BrowserLab. (See link below) In IE8 the @font-face is broken, but the whole layout is as well. https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html#browsers=WXPIE9000%2CWXPCH18000%2CWXPIE8000%2CWXPIE7000;view=0;url=http%3A%2F%2Fachieveee.com%2Fpareekshum%2F;zoom=100;state=use

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font';
  src: url('font.eot');
  src: local('☺'),
         url('font.otf') format('opentype');
}
```

more here: http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/

maybe try with some other (than fsq) font-face generator, fe. http://fontface.codeandmore.com/

Comment: I done that but its not working.My website link is http://achieveee.com/pareekshum .

Comment: Actually I converted my .ttf font to other from website http://fontface.codeandmore.com/.It provide sample code that also not working in ie.I don't know what issue is going on.